# what port-range will be chosen when bind9 is forwarding a dns query?

Tags: networking, dns, udp, bind, network-security

A request like:

asking
client Desktop 1-> locaDns(Bind9-hostA) 2-> DNSServer(whatever)

answering
client Desktop <-4 locaDns(Bind9-hostA) <-3 DNSServer(whatever)

I want to know which port-range will be used in step 2 when locaDns(Bind9-hostA) forwarding the request from client to DNSServer be default. 
Can we configure it ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, but [this is all documented](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/cur/9.8/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html):

```
[ use-v4-udp-ports { port_list }; ]
[ avoid-v4-udp-ports { port_list }; ]
[ use-v6-udp-ports { port_list }; ]
[ avoid-v6-udp-ports { port_list }; ]
```